# zoom in slowing down then stopping completely

Tags: modeling

Zoom in slowing down then stopping not close enough to object. I want to be able to zoom in closer and a lot of the time Blender won't let me.

Also I click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> with vertices selected tell it to merge at center and nothing happens.

Comment: Please do not use questions to rant and familiarize yourself with the [code of conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) on this website.

Answer (score 1):

Go to *View Option* and then click *Frame Selected*, it will zoom in. Also, change view from perspective to orthographic, this will allow zoom in to (shortcut <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>).

Regarding merging, try increasing distance or you might need to cross check at bottom right if vertices reduced before and after operation or not.

Comment: thank u sir....